# Translate sql with COUNT into LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I can't seem to find a way to translate this sql into LINQ.
It will give me all unique rows, and count the value of NumberOf field in each row.

```
SELECT Id, SupId, Text, ExternalId, NumberOf, count(s.NumberOf)
FROM Stock s
GROUP BY s.Id, s.SupId, s.Text, s.ExternalId, s.NumberOf
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like this:

```
var consolidatedChildren =
    from s in Stock
    group s by new
    {
        s.Id, 
        s.SupId, 
        s.Text, 
        s.ExternalId, 
        s.NumberOf
    } into gs
    select new
    {
        Id = gs.Key.School,
        SupId =gs.Key.SupId, 
        Text = gs.Key.Text, 
        ExternalId =gs.Key.ExternalId, 
        NumberOf =gs.Key.NumberOf,
        Count = gs.Count()  //--------------> Count of Rows
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Group your data by an anonymous class.

```
var query = from s in Stock 
            group s by new {s.Id, s.SupId, s.Text, s.ExternalId} into g
            select new {g.Key.Id, g.Key.SupId, g.Key.Text, g.Key.ExternalId, Count = g.Count()};
```